# Is there a Microsoft Access Database cache?

Tags: ms-access

Please forgive me if I sound out of my element here because it's the first time I've been tasked with working with MS Access.

**Problem:**
I came into work today to find that records from August 22, 2017 to Present are missing (We do a printout every 1-2 months and more recent entries were in the most recent print out, but not displayed in Access). We probably average 2-4 records per day, so there's a lot missing.

To my knowledge there is no back up. I was left with minimal instruction (relatively new job for me) was told to double click here (desktop icon) and enter info there (a table).

I'm trying to locate the data on my machine to see if it is stored somewhere, just not displaying.

I get this error when trying to open the .ldb shortcut:

> Unrecognized database format 'C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\Database_Contacts_Orders.ldb'.

But I've always received this.

I've created a table entry for today and when I restart Access it is still there.

I'm hoping to find a cache of this info somewhere or a way to restore it (without a backup).

Also, I'm not the only one who has access to this machine.

Comment: There's no caching per se. The ldb file is just a locking file to determine who is logged into the database.. This isn't really a progamming question so it might get closed

Comment: If it is improperly copied to another location, the copy may have the records your looking for. But you would have to find the other copy to merge them. It happens when people don't know what they are doing.

Comment: Thank you @dbmitch Are you saying that info is gone?

Comment: No idea - could be a number of reasons. If you're viewing on a form it could be a filter or the query that the report is based on. Only way to know for sure is to look at the underlying table. If it's a front-end back-end scenario then the server backups should have a backup copy to restore.

Comment: Access does a lot of caching, but it's all in the database file itself. There's a good chance you're out of luck, but using third party tools, data might be recoverable. Just _don't_ compact and repair, or it's gone. Tool recommendations are off-topic, but a quick google results in a lot of tools.

Comment: I had an odd thought about this, and not really related directly to your question exactly, although I believe that has already been answered. Your worries may be misplaced here, if there is any sort of backend attached to this database, this *may* be normal proceedure to find the data missing. It could be purged and archived or something like that. It's probably best to ask the question if you are truely concerned, but there really isn't much you could do about it either way. On a side note, the *.ldb file is the *current working portion* of the database, its not really meant to be opened.